# Unable to get the correct regex pattern to change a property into a value setter

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, properties, constructor

Assuming I have some object like, with LOTS of properties:

```
public class SomeObject
{
  public SomeOtherObject1 Property1 { get; set; }
  public SomeOtherObject2 Property2 { get; set; }
  public SomeOtherObject3 Property3 { get; set; }
  public SomeOtherObject4 Property4 { get; set; }
  public SomeOtherObject5 Property5 { get; set; }
  public SomeOtherObject6 Property6 { get; set; }
}
```

It would be really cool if I could create a constructor and copy the properties into the constructor...

```
public class SomeObject
{
  public SomeObject
  {
    public SomeOtherObject1 Property1 { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherObject2 Property2 { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherObject3 Property3 { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherObject4 Property4 { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherObject5 Property5 { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherObject6 Property6 { get; set; }
  }

  public SomeOtherObject1 Property1 { get; set; }
  public SomeOtherObject2 Property2 { get; set; }
  public SomeOtherObject3 Property3 { get; set; }
  public SomeOtherObject4 Property4 { get; set; }
  public SomeOtherObject5 Property5 { get; set; }
  public SomeOtherObject6 Property6 { get; set; }
}
```

And use [Visual Studio's Find And Replace with Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) to change the highlighted lines in the constructor from:

```
    public SomeOtherObject1 Property1 { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherObject2 Property2 { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherObject3 Property3 { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherObject4 Property4 { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherObject5 Property5 { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherObject6 Property6 { get; set; }
```

to:

```
    this.Property1 = new SomeOtherObject1();
    this.Property2 = new SomeOtherObject2();
    this.Property3 = new SomeOtherObject3();
    this.Property4 = new SomeOtherObject4();
    this.Property5 = new SomeOtherObject5();
    this.Property6 = new SomeOtherObject6();
```

First I tried:

> public\s{:i}\s{:i}\s{\sget;\sset;\s}
>
> this.\2 = new \1();

Then I thought maybe it was a line issue, so I tried:

> ^\s*public\s{:i}\s{:i}\s{\sget;\sset;\s}.$
>
> this.\2 = new \1();

Anyone else have any thought on how to get this to work?

Comment: Generally, backreferences are captured using () not {}, but I've never used the Visual Studio find and replace, so I can say for certain.  This would mean your find would be: `^\s*public\s(:i)\s(:i)\s{\sget;\sset;\s}.$` instead.  You might also need to escape the other braces: `^\s*public\s(:i)\s(:i)\s\{\s*get;\s*set;\s*\}.*$`

Comment: In Visual Studio, it's {}, not () for capturing

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity .. yeah as sinelaw said its {}... Thank you Microsoft!  (Took me a while to figure that out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the {} around get; set;. Also, I've used :b instead of \s and allowed for more than one. Here:

```
public:b+{:i}:b+{:i}:b*\{:b*get;:b*set;:b*\}
```

And as you wrote:

```
this.\2 = new \1();
```